# PushViewController for a button click

Tags: xcode, button, pushviewcontroller

PushViewController for a button click

Here's my code:

```
ViewController.h

import < UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface StaffLoginViewController : UIViewController
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *StaffUsername;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *StaffPassword;
- (IBAction)LoginClicked:(id)sender;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *arrayLogin;
- (IBAction)ResignKeyboardClicked:(id)sender;

@end

ViewController.m

- (IBAction)LoginClicked:(id)sender{

ViewController *view = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController"     bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:view animated:YES];
}
```

I only have the code for modalViewController. Please help! Thanks:)

Comment: Do you mean to push it on an a UINavigationController-stack?
Please specify your question a little better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
[self presentModalViewController:view animated:YES];
```

you should use

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
```

but, but, but you should have NavigationController as well, for example

AppDelegate.m
......

```
StaffLoginViewController *vc = [[StaffLoginViewController alloc] init];
self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

.......

Comment: Is it possible if I want the normal button, not the navigation controller button ?

Comment: I am not sure understand you. Please, describe workflow of your app and what you want to do.